# Performance issues with angular web application used on a touchscreen

Tags: angularjs, performance, qt, cpu, qtwebkit

I have developed a single-page-application using `AngularJS` and `Bootstrap3`.
I see that a touch or a swipe on any clickable area of the screen makes the CPU hit `90%` utilization (at times even `100%`). 
It's an embedded device and I am using a 1Ghz 1GB RAM system to run my web page on a `QTWebView`.

Have you ever come across this kind of performance issues with Angular apps?

Comment: That would be pretty much expected, I'm afraid. The whole point of using Qt would be, I hope, not to have to use javascript on top of html, but to use Qt Quick. If you implement the same with Qt Quick, it should hopefully perform fine.

Comment: Why in the world would that be expected? Merely touching or swiping in an Angular app running in regular Chrome/WebKit doesn't cause the CPU to spike to 100%. Why would it be "pretty much expected" that it should do that when running in an embedded Qt webview?

Comment: Keeping rest of the things common, I changed the application to a ver basic HTML document with some text on it (no AngularJS/ no JS/ no controls). Even then the swipes on the screen lead to unexpected CPU spikes (45%+). Does that mean that JS framework is not the only culprit?